# A loop inside an ajax call- I'm confused about order of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, face-detection

I feel like I don't complete understand how ajax calls work (I promise I tried to understand but although I thought I do, my code doesn't work as expected).
This is what I'm trying to do:
I have server side code which simply returns an array of image urls.
For each image, I'm doing facedetection using a client side face detection library.
After doing face detection on ALL images I need to draw them one by one on canvas (this is not really relevant anymore).
What happens in reality is that I first get the alert of "done with looking for faces" and only then I get the alerts with the urls of the images and it uses the same url for all of them.
I also set "async" to false because I thought this will make the order of events work as I expect it to.
Please let me know if I wasn't clear and thank you so much in advance!

```
//Call FB api from server side script
function callApi(userId, token) {
      $.ajax({
          "type": "GET",
          "url": API_ROUTE + "?userid=" + userId + "&token=" + token,
          "async": false,  //setting to false because we don't want to start drawing before face detection is done
          success: function(data, status, xhr) {
              face_coords = []; //Array that stores face locations for each image (indexs are respective to 
                                    //image indexes in aImages)
             for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  var img_url = data[i];
                  img_url.replace('https://', 'http://'); //To avoid cross-domain issues

                  // collect all images
                  var oImg = new Image();
                  oImg.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
                  oImg.src = img_url;
                  aImages.push(oImg);
                  $("#myPicture").attr("src", oImg.src).load(function() {
                      var coords = $('#myPicture').faceDetection();
                      //find the face detected with the highest confidence
                      if (coords.length > 0) {
                          var highest_confidence = 0,
                              highest_c = 0;
                          for (var c = 0; c < coords.length; c++) {
                              if (coords[c].confidence > highest_confidence) {
                                  highest_confidence = coords[c].confidence;
                                  highest_c = c;
                              }
                          }
                      }
                      face_coords.push(coords[highest_c]);
                      alert ("done with " + $('#myPicture').get(0).src)
                  });
              }
          }
      });
      alert("done with looking for faces");
      var canvas = $('#myCanvas').get(0);
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      //draw first image
      context.drawImage(aImages[0], 0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, aImages[0].height / aImages[0].width * CANVAS_WIDTH);
      changeSlide(); //call on the first image in order to not waste 5 seconds
      timer = setInterval(changeSlide, 5000); // set inner timer
  }
```

Comment: success will be called if ajax call is successful. What is confusing you ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try .done() rather than success.

```
function getData() {
return $.ajax({
    url : 'example.com',
    type: 'GET'
});
}

function handleData(data /* , textStatus, jqXHR */ ) {
    alert(data);
    //do some stuff
}

getData().done(handleData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is when you get the image element with the same ID for all the loop!
You have to add a specific value to your image elements.Now it seems you try to affect the same element all the time with the id **myPicture**. `$("#myPicture").attr("src", oImg.src)`;
Try to add a postfix to your elements `$("#myPicture_" + something )`.

And aditionally you shoud put this code

```
 face_coords.push(coords[highest_c]);
                  alert ("done with " + $('#myPicture').get(0).src)
```

inside the image load function because berore load completed you get the alert!

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I'm still getting the alert "done with looking for faces";
before it's done detecting faces.

Comment: Take a look a the description I think load is not finished and you get the alert.So put it at the last row inside the image load function.and tell me